# How to perform Join in Firebase using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, database, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database with a dispensary and an associated location.

[image: Database layout]

My goal is to return all dispensaries and their corresponding locations. I've been trying to do it like this

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { Dispensary } from './model/Dispensary';
import { Location } from './model/Location';

export const getDispensaries = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    let dispensaries: Dispensary[] = []
    await admin.database().ref("/dispensary").once("value")
      .then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

            var dispensaryValues = childSnapshot.val();
            var name =  dispensaryValues["name"];
            var locationID = dispensaryValues["locationID"];

            admin.database().ref("/location").child(locationID).once("value")
                .then(function(innerSnapShot) {
                    innerSnapShot.forEach(function(innerChildSnapShot) {

                        var locationValues = innerChildSnapShot.val();
                        var latitude = locationValues["latitude"];
                        var longitude =  locationValues["longitude"];

                        let location: Location = new Location(latitude, longitude);
                        let dispensary: Dispensary = new Dispensary(name, location);
                        dispensaries.push(dispensary);
                    });
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
            });
      });
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
    res.send(dispensaries)
});
```

and my Dispensary and Location classes look like this

```
export class Dispensary {
    name: string;
    location: Location;

    constructor(name: string, location: Location) {
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
    }
}

export class Location {
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;

    constructor(latitude: number, longitude: number) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

Now this code returns me an empty array []. I tried getting just the dispensaries and that works but when I remove the async/await from the dispensary call it returns an empty array again.

Also, when I try to add an await to the locations call it tells me I'm missing an async, but when I add the async it tells me `Type Promise<void> is not assignable to type 'void'`

Am I approaching this the completely wrong way? Any help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: Why don't you keep the location on the dispensary record, are the locations used more than once?

Answer (score 0):

Your primary issue was that you were returning the value of `dispensaries` without waiting first for each location to be retrieved, parsed, assembled and then added to the `dispensaries` array.

The below code goes through the proper flow of operations to zip the two locations together.

```
export const getDispensaries = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    // STEP: Define reused database locations
    const DISPENSARY_REF = admin.database().ref("/dispensary");
    const LOCATION_REF = admin.database().ref("/location");

    // STEP: Fetch list of dispensaries
    DISPENSARY_REF.once("value")
        .then(function (allDispensariesSnapshot) {
            // STEP: Define array to store all tasks so they can be run in parallel
            const dispensaryPromises: Promise<Dispensary>[] = [];

            // DataSnapshot.forEach() is syncronous - so we can't use async/await syntax here
            // STEP: Iterate over each dispensary in the database
            allDispensariesSnapshot.forEach(function (dispensarySnapshot) {
                // STEP: Extract dispensary data
                // Ref: /dispensary/someDispensaryID
                // Available Data: { locationID, name }
                const dispensaryValues = dispensarySnapshot.val();
                const { locationID, name } = dispensaryValues;

                // Fetch location data & resolve with completed dispensary object
                // STEP: Fetch needed data from other database locations
                const currentDispensaryPromise = LOCATION_REF.child(locationID).once("value")
                    .then(function (locationSnapshot) {
                        // STEP: Extract data
                        // Ref: /location/someLocationID
                        // Available Data: { latitude, longitude }
                        const locationValues = locationSnapshot.val();
                        const { latitude, longitude } = locationValues;

                        // STEP: Assemble objects
                        const location: Location = new Location(latitude, longitude);

                        // STEP: Return the final object
                        return new Dispensary(name, location);
                    });

                // STEP: Add this task to list of tasks
                dispensaryPromises.push(currentDispensaryPromise);
            });

            // STEP: wait for all tasks
            return Promise.all(dispensaryPromises);
        })
        .then(dispensaries => {
            // Objects were retrieved successfully
            // STEP: Return data to client
            res.json(dispensaries);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // Something went wrong
            // STEP: Log & return error to client
            console.log(error); // log full error here
            res.status(500).json({error: error.message}); // but only return error message to client
        });
});
```

If at a later juncture, you need to fetch more than one location, you would update the `currentDispensaryPromise` to:

```
// Fetch other data & resolve with completed dispensary object
// STEP: Fetch needed data from other locations
const currentDispensaryPromise = Promise.all([
    LOCATION_REF.child(locationID).once("value"),
    USER_REF.child(ownerID).child('name').once("value") // with locations that have lots of data, fetch only what's needed
])
    .then(([locationSnapshot, ownerNameSnapshot]) => {
        // STEP: Extract data
        // Ref: /location/someLocationID
        // Available Data: { latitude, longitude }
        const locationValues = locationSnapshot.val();
        const { latitude, longitude } = locationValues;

        // Ref: /user/someOwnerID/name (string)
        const ownerName = ownerNameSnapshot.val();

        // STEP: Assemble objects
        const location: Location = new Location(latitude, longitude);
        const owner: Owner = new Owner(ownerID, ownerName);

        // STEP: Return the final object
        return new Dispensary(name, location, owner);
    });
```

**Note:** If this pairing of dispensary and location data is used more often than not, consider merging the objects together rather than storing them separately.

## Other notes

There is no need to use objects for `Dictionary` and `Location`, just specifying the shape of the object as a type is sufficient.

```
type Dispensary = {
    name: number;
    location: Location;
}

type Location = {
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;
}

const {name, locationID} = dispensarySnapshot.val();
const location = locationSnapshot.val() as Location;
return {name, location} as Dispensary;
```

However, if you wanted to keep them as objects, you can flatten your definitions:

```
class Dispensary {
    constructor(public name: string, public location: Location) {}
}

class Location {
    constructor(public latitude: number, public longitude: number) {}
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you for the fast reply and helpful tips I didn't even know I needed! I haven't got a chance to implement it yet but I'll try it out sometime this week and update you.